# How to transfer objects from ArrayList to LinkedList

Tags: java

I need to transfer all the data I got in ArrayList to LinkedList and display all it all just like I did with ArrayList. I failed to display it out when I got the data transferred to LinkedList. The code is as below :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class testEmployee
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        ArrayList <Employee> empArray = new ArrayList();
        LinkedList yrIncm = new LinkedList();

    Employee emp;
    int empNum;
    boolean found = true;

    empNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How many employees information do you want to store?"));

    for (int i = 0; i < empNum; i++)
    {
        String sEmpId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the employee's ID");
        String sEmpName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the employee's Name");
        String sEmpPosition = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the employee's position");
        Double dSalary = Double.parseDouble (JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please enter the employee's monthly salary"));

        emp = new Employee (sEmpId, sEmpName, sEmpPosition, dSalary);

        empArray.add (emp);
    }

    System.out.println ("Employee that obtains a monthly salary more than RM 2000.00");
    System.out.println ("===========================================================");
    for (int i = 0; i<empArray.size(); i++)
    {
        if (empArray.get(i).getSalary() > 2000)
        {
            empArray.get(i).display(); // This will display the info using ArrayList
        }
    }

    System.out.println ("\nEmployee that have yearly income greater than RM 80,000");
    System.out.println ("=======================================================");
    for (int i = 0; i<empArray.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((empArray.get(i).getSalary() * 12) > 80000)
        {

            yrIncm.add (empArray.get(i)); // Is this the correct way of transferring the data? 

            System.out.println (yrIncm); // How do you print it all back? 
        }
    }

   }
}
```

The `display()` in class Employee:

```
public void display()
{
    System.out.println ("\nEmployee's ID : " + sEmpId);
    System.out.println ("Employee's Name : " + sEmpName);
    System.out.println ("Employee's Position : " + sEmpPosition);
    System.out.println ("Employee's Salary : RM " + df.format (dSalary));
}
```

I'm unable to use the method `display()` to print it out from the LinkedList. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to display a full list of your objects, you should not use `display()`. You should instead override the `toString()` method in `Employee`. You can then print a list and all its elements will be properly printed.

Comment: note: if this is not home-work that explicitly requires using linked list, then there are very few reasons to prefer this data structure over array list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i<empArray.size(); i++)
{
    if ((empArray.get(i).getSalary() * 12) > 80000)
    {
        LinkedList yrIncm = new LinkedList();
```

You create a new linked list each time and put exactly one element into it. Then you print out the one-element list and toss it away.

While the above is certainly wrong, I don't see where you imagine `display()` entering this picture. Your linked list never leaves the for-loop.

Comment: What a silly mistakes, I've corrected it. Now for the `display()`, as you can see `empArray.get(i).display();` will call `display()` and print it out, and I've done it with Arraylist. Now I want to do the same with the LinkedList that I created and it seems that I can't call the method to print the exact same info. How do I make it possible?

Comment: Java collections are iterated over using an `Iterator` returned from the `iterator()` method. A shorthand notation for that is the _enhanced for_ loop: `for (Employee emp : listOfEmployees) { emp.display(); }` You should use this instead of `get(i)`, even for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinkedList.addAll to get all the elements of the ArrayList.

```
LinkedList<Employee> yrIncm = new LinkedList();

yrIncm.addAll(empArray);
yrIncm.forEach(employee -> employee.display());
```

The problem with your code is that you are re-creating the LinkedList everytime and probably trying to call display() on a linkedlist instead of employee oobject.